# Edit action does not update in the database ASP.NET MVC with session parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to edit the user details from the database the user is logged-in to, after logging in I take the session:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(Login login, string ReturnUrl = "")
{
        .....
        if (v != null)
        {
            if ((bool)!v.IsEmailVerified)
            {
               ........
            }

            if (string.Compare(Crypto.Hash(login.password), v.password) == 0)
            {
               ....
               Session["EmailID"] = v.email;
            }
       }
}
```

For login and edit actions they have different controllers, login is in the `userController` while edit actions are in the `userdashController`, where for edit actions:

```
db_userEntities1 db = new db_userEntities1()

public ActionResult EditProfile(string EmailId)
{
    EmailId = Session["EmailID"].ToString();

    var edit = db.tbl_user.Where(i => i.email == EmailId).FirstOrDefault();

    return View(edit);
}

// POST: Customer/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProfile(string EmailId, tbl_user user)
{
    using (db_userEntities1 dc = new db_userEntities1())
    {
        // TODO: Add update logic here

        var userdata = dc.tbl_user.Where(s => s.email == user.email).FirstOrDefault();
        dc.Entry(userdata).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        dc.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

When I save it goes straight to the index but the database hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?  What type database are you using?  Update will not work in some cases if the data isn't in the database.  Then you need to use insert instead of update.

Comment: try Debug with adding this line of the save :  
        int modif = dc.SaveChanges();
        Debug.WriteLine(modif);
Zero will mean not saved, you can also put other value in message that are used in your EditProfile to check what happen.

Comment: I don't see any updates. What are you trying to save?